# Is there any way to limit random in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, random

Let's say i want to generate a set of coordinates(x,y), using `rand`. Take **any one** point of the generated random set, the **distance** between **this point** and **those points( nearest/the first layer) surround it** could be limited in certain range. The overview effect looks 'these random points are **uniformly distributed**.

Answer (score 1):

All n points must be inside a circle. The diameter of this circle is the maximum distance (d_max) between any two points. Use polar coordinates: `r = (d_max / 2) * sqrt(rand(n, 1)); phi = 2 * pi * rand(n, 1);` The square root is needed to get uniform areal density. Convert polar coordinates to Descartes coordinates the usual way: `x = x0 + r .* cos(phi); y = y0 + r .* sin(phi);` where `(x0, y0)` gives the center of the circle.

The result for `d_max = 10`:

[image: Scattered points]

The histogram of the distances between points:

[image: Distance histogram]

Comment: @Ivy, what do you exactly mean by "those surround it"?

Comment: @Ivy, I mean, which point do "surround" a given point, and which points do not?

Comment: `pol2cart` can be used for conversion from polar to Cartesian coordinates (http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/pol2cart.html).

Comment: @ Ivy, as kol used rand function, the resulting samples will always be scattered but all the samples will be bounded with in the circle with centre x0, y0 and d_max/2 radius. His answers fits your requirement best.

Comment: @kol:The point be surrounded, in your words,'a given point', is one of the generated random points.

Comment: Converting uniformly-distributed `r` and `phi` to Cartesian coordinates won't give you a distribution with uniform areal density.

Comment: @user57368 That is true, the points will be scattered more densely close to the center. I will try to figure out a transformation and edit my post.

Comment: @user57368 Done. I used a formula from Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_distribution

Answer (score 1):

Limiting random co-ordinates about a point (x,y) with in a distance 'r' is more like selecting random points in a circle with centre (x,y) and radius 'r'.

Below should help

http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/294-generate-random-points-inside-a-circle

Comment: The maximal distance between any pair of points inside a circle is the diameter, not the radius.

Comment: Actually the points have to be on the circle. It is "The maximal distance between any pair of points ON the circle is the diameter, not the radius". what exactly is the point of your post?

Answer (score -1):

Use Modulus

```
mod([1:5],3)
ans =
    1     2     0     1     2
```

http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/techdoc/ref/mod.html